# Dojo dtl tag logic not working

Tags: javascript, dojo, django-templates

I'm using Dojo dtl (Django Template Language) to render a widget. I pass it an array with a few objects in it. It iterates over the objects and their subarrays just fine, but I'm applying an 'if' condition that isn't working:

```
<div>
  {% for layer in layers %}
  <dl>
    <dt>{{ layer.name }}</dt>
      <dd>
        {% for symbol in layer.symbols %}
        <div>
          {% if symbol.type == "asdfjkl" %}
          This should never happen!
          {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </dd>
    </dl>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Even though symbol.type will never equal 'asdfjkl', it's still printing the message inside the blocks.

I know this isn't supported anymore by Dojo, but they don't really have a template engine, so it's pretty much all I have.

Answer (score 2):

```
{% ifequal symbol.type "asdfjkl" %}smth{% endifequal %}
```